# Avoiding copies in Direct2D

Tags: windows, 2d, direct2d

I have an in-memory bitmap which is (for example) 1Mb.

Before drawing the bitmap, **Task Manager** shows that my app is using roughly 5MB (the bitmap is already initialized at that point). And here's the problem:

```
calling CreateBitmap() -> memory usage is 6.1MB 
calling DrawBitmap() -> no changes
calling EndDraw() -> memory usage is 8.2MB
```

Can I avoid this? It's not a big deal, but still...

Comment: Task Manager isn't the best way to assess memory behavior, but it does provide good hints.  And just because memory usage went up, doesn't mean that it actually made a copy of anything.  When you call DrawBitmap twice in a row for the same image, does the memory usage change?  Does memory appear to leak if you continually call {Create,Draw,End}Bitmap over and over?

Comment: No, there is no memory leak if i continually call those functions.

Comment: Then it's not a memory leak. You're just seeing deferred first-time initialization costs.